# How to remove the carriage return and replace it with a space in a text file?

Tags: perl

I am reading from a text file so what i want is:
to remove that carriage return and add a space between the words.

I tried this but i am getting an error

```
 $text =~ s/\n+/\s/g;
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The right side of the substitution is a string, not a regex, so you put a literal space instead of `\s`:

```
$text =~ s/\n+/ /g;
```

Answer (score 2):

Is like **Zaid** said.

If you want to use a more powerful (crossplatform) regex, i suggest this one

```
(\r?\n|\r\n?)+
```

So your code becomes:

```
$text =~ s/(\r?\n|\r\n?)+/ /g;
```

if you wanna do it with a one-line command, you could do:

```
perl -pi -e 's/(\r?\n|\r\n?)+/ /g' your_file
```